# Convert python regex pattern to lua

Tags: python, regex, lua

I have a pattern but I don't know how to convert to Lua pattern
here is my pattern:

```
(?P<Protocol>https?:\/\/)?(?P<Subdomain>\w*\.)?(?P<Domain>(?:[a-z0-9\-]{1,})\.(?:[^\s\/\.]{2,}))(?P<Path>\/proxy)?(?P<Params>(?:\?|\#)[^\s\/\?\:]*)
```

anyone can help me to convert or convert it for me?

Comment: Please, read the rules.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to search for online tools such as https://regex101.com/.

I could not find one for LUA, as it seems that LUA has its own language for "patterns" that are not regex. This was a 2' search so maybe I missed something.

Instead there seem to be good documentation sources out there such as

- https://riptutorial.com/lua/example/20315/lua-pattern-matching
- https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html

You would need to provide a minimal reproducible example if you wish LUA-fluent users to help you here.